# Getting undefined variable when calling function from another function

Tags: javascript, function

Scratching my head. I'm getting an undefined error when trying to call a function. Thing is, when I print to the console I can see the data being passed clearly.

> Uncaught TypeError: convos is undefined

function1

```
function fetchConversation(userID){

//loop through 
usersms.forEach(function (sms,counter) {

//get userid from  iteration
var userid_loop = sms.details[0].user.id;

//only display convo from specific user
if(userid_loop === userID){

//get all messages from this one user
var conversation = sms.details;

//transfer conversation to next function to display
showConversation(conversation);
//
}
//
});
}
```

function2

```
function showConversation(myconvo){
        
var convos = myconvo;
        
//iterate and append conversion
convos.forEach(function (msg,counter) {
        
console.log(msg.message);//prints all messages in the log
        
});
}
showConversation()//Uncaught TypeError: convos is undefined
```

Comment: Try doing `showConversation(myconvo)` instead of `showConversation()`

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon: yes I did try that. It would have been an easy fix. I wouldn't be here.

Comment: Why are you calling `showConversation()` on its own?

Comment: @Nick: display result in html from the index page. I do this with a different function and it works. This one is undefined

Comment: Well just to be totally clear what your error is: if you do `showConversation()`, you have passed no arguments, meaning `myconvo` is `undefined`. Then you try to do `undefined.forEach`, which will explode because it's not an array.

Comment: @Nick: I'm listening. So it's a big bug then because if it's not an array how am I able to loop through and log result in the console? Weird.

Comment: Yeah, I mean you clearly use it correctly _inside_ the `fetchConversation` function

Comment: First error - you are not passing in arguments into your function. Second error - msg.message doesn't exist, it's just msg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649486/getting-undefined-variable-when-calling-function-from-another-function#answer-65649649. Also, the counter is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to enter something within the brackets of showConversation().

You are assigning convos to myconvo, but myconvo doesn't exist because you didn't enter it as a parameter (value in the brackets).

Comment: What would that variable be? I tried with different variables and get undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is that you are not passing in any arguments to the function.

Your second error is that msg.message doesn't exist - it's just msg by itself.

Also, the counter is unnecessary in this case.

```js
function showConversation(myconvo) {
  var convos = myconvo;
  //iterate and append conversion
  convos.forEach(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg); //prints all messages in the log
  });
}
showConversation(["element1", "element2"])
```

You also have an error here:

```
function fetchConversation(userID){

//loop through
usersms.forEach(function (sms,counter) {

//get userid from  iteration
var userid_loop = sms.details[0].user.id;

//only display convo from specific user
if(userid_loop === userID){

//get all messages from this one user
var conversation = sms.details; //actually gets the details of the element it is iterating through, not all of them

//transfer conversation to next function to display
showConversation(conversation); //sends the details one by one for each iteration
//
}
//
});
}
```

Fix:

```
function fetchConversation(userID){
var conversation=[]
//loop through
usersms.forEach(function (sms,counter) {

//get userid from  iteration
var userid_loop = sms.details[0].user.id;

//only display convo from specific user
if(userid_loop === userID){

//get all messages from this one user
conversation.push(sms.details);
}
});
//transfer conversation to next function to display
showConversation(conversation);
}
```

Comment: What would be those elements?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. I just fixed it so it works. It looks like you are trying to pass through snippets of a chat.